# Ultraviolet Filter Effect Simulation

Tags: iphone, ios, filter, gpuimage

I need to simulate [Ultraviolet](http://www.geeky-gadgets.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/UofCCancerCenter_610x406.png) effect in my iOS app.

I tried applying Histogram Filter -> Saturation -> Grey Scale. But that didnt work. Can anybody suggest me how to get this working.

Can I use [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) for this? What filter combination needs to be applied to get this effect?

Comment: I tried to apply Sharpness->GreyScale->Auto Enhance. This is how it looks [now.](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18599294/test.jpg). Can anybody guide me in improving this image?

Comment: hi can you show me how you combine filter? I am stuck at this.